# Show the solution for dirichlet problem for the Leplace equation is zero in a certain domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Given a domain $\Omega \subset R^n$, consider nthe dirichlet problem for the Leplace equation, that is:
$$ 
∆u = 0 \: in \: x \in \Omega \\
u(x) = 0 \: in \: x \in \Omega
$$

Show that if there is a solution $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ is exactly zero

Comment: maximal principle

Comment: could you possibly also make use of green's identity 1 which states that the directional derivate of u along v (where v is the outer normal vector) on the boundary $\Omega$ is 0 and then state that implies any solution is exactly zero?